# RSA Public exponent defaults to 65537. What should this value be?  What are the impacts of my choices?

Tags: c#, math, rsa, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I'm creating unit tests for software that may encounter different exponent sizes. ([see section 3.3.1 of this RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4871.txt))

How can I use Bouncy Castle, or any other C# library to generate a RSA key pair [that doesn't have a key size of 65537.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3110/371)

If the answer is that I can directly modify this, as long as I update the private key as well, what specific changes (or re-computation) should I make for the public and private key?

Here is the sample code that I'm using to create the key with the exponent of 65537:

```
        // Create key
        RsaKeyPairGenerator generator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        var param = new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 1024);
        generator.Init(param);
         AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair= generator.GenerateKeyPair();

        // Save to export format
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo info = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyPair.Public);
        byte[] ret =  info.GetEncoded();
        string ovalue1 = Convert.ToBase64String(ret);

        // Read from export format
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ovalue1);
        AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publicKeyBytes);

        RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;
        RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
        rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArray();
        rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArray();
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
```

Comment: `KeyGenerationParameters` has a subclass `RSAKeyGenerationParameters` that can be instantiated with a public exponent.

Comment: @BrettHale - That solved it for me!  If you want the rep for that answer, feel free to post it ..

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@BrettHale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906839/brett-hale) I was able to solve the issue.

This is how to create a key pair in Bouncy Castle

```
      // Create key
        RsaKeyPairGenerator generator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();

        /*
         * This value should be a Fermat number. 0x10001 (F4) is current recommended value. 3 (F1) is known to be safe also.
         * 3, 5, 17, 257, 65537, 4294967297, 18446744073709551617,
         * 
         * Practically speaking, Windows does not tolerate public exponents which do not fit in a 32-bit unsigned integer. Using e=3 or e=65537 works "everywhere". 
         */
        BigInteger exponentBigInt = new BigInteger(exponent.ToString());

        var param = new RsaKeyGenerationParameters(
            exponentBigInt, // new BigInteger("10001", 16)  publicExponent
            new SecureRandom(),  // SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"),//prng
            keyStrength, //strength
            certaninty);//certainty
        generator.Init(param);
```

Additional links that relate to his recommendation to use RSAKeyGenerationParameters include:

- [Why is exponent value 65537 used, what are the alternatives and impacts?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3110/371)
- [What is certainty, and what is the correct value for this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3114/371) (hint: it depends on key length)

Comment: These recommendations are largely due to [Coppersmith's attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith's_Attack) and its variants.