# Generate a 2048 key with custom exponent size?

Tags: c#, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Is there a way to generate a `2048` RSA key pair, using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` with a custom defined exponent?

```
new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048); // = 65537 always
```

For example, I want to set the exponent to `65535`, but the hard-coded value seems to be `65537`.

I've looked around, but was unable to find any information.

I am trying to generate a **new** key pair, not import an existing key, using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

I know that importing an already existent key, I can define modulus, exponent and other factors.

If its not possible, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: NIST requires 65537: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-78-4.pdf  Good backgrounder [is here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3113)

Comment: @HansPassant I am porting a client/server from c++ to c# and the client currently only uses 65535,  to receive the public key which I am unsure at which point all clients variations will be updated.

Comment: Well, ImportParameters() is the key.  Note that the code in the answer might be helping too much with Reverse().

Comment: @HansPassant sorry. I don't get it, wouldn't change the exponent of an already generated keypair simple kill it?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) cryptographic library. Use `RsaKeyPairGenerator` class for key generating with [RsaKeyGenerationParameters](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/b19e68a517e56ef08cd2e50df4dcb8a96ddbe507/crypto/src/crypto/parameters/RsaKeyGenerationParameters.cs) for setting of your public RSA exponent. See [here](http://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2013/03/18/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-bouncy-castle#subject-public-key) the example with key pair generating. But pay attention with the choice of the exponent. The public RSA exponent should be a [Fermat Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). See question [Impacts of not using RSA exponent of 65537](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/impacts-of-not-using-rsa-exponent-of-65537) for more details about choosing of the exponent.

See also useful posts about certificate generating [Using Bouncy Castle from .NET](http://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2013/03/18/using-bouncy-castle-from-net). For your convenience you may generate Bouncy Castle certificate and convert it to .NET `X509Certificate2` object.

**Update:**

I think the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279595/rsa-public-exponent-defaults-to-65537-what-should-this-value-be-what-are-the) with using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` may help you.